# Which identity is being used to get $\sin(wa)\cos(wt)=\sin(w(a+t))+\sin(w(a-t))$?

Tags: trigonometry

Which identity is being used to get $\sin(wa)\cos(wt)=\frac{\sin(w(a+t))+\sin(w(a-t))}{2}$?

Couldn't find it among the trigonometric identities.

Comment: Name any trigonometric identities you checked

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities http://www.sosmath.com/trig/Trig5/trig5/trig5.html

Comment: Check the section [Product-to-sum and sum-to-product identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities) there (and correct the error in your post)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Thanks! What error in my post do you mean?

Comment: @user42141 You are missing a factor of $2$ in your formula (it shows up when you add the basic identities in my answer below).

Answer (score 3):

Add $$\sin (x+y) = \sin x\cos y + \cos x\sin y $$
and
$$\sin (x-y) = \sin x\cos y - \cos x\sin y. $$

See what you get and apply it to your problem.